# How to add facets for this case in solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a product which is a mobile and one of the search facets of it is **Networking** under which the following are most likely to appear.

1. Bluetooth
2. Wifi
3. GPS
4. 4G

Now, for every product I have a Product attribute table i.e. a collection of key-value pairs. For example,

```
Manufacture=Apple
Price=900
```

where **Manufacture** and **Price** are keys. Each key is holding a single value. But, for Networking, a product can have all of the above listed features or a subset of them.
Now, my question is the user should be able to filter the mobiles with them as facets.

One workaround would be to create a product attribute called **Networking** with a value like this..

```
Networking=Wifi|Bluetooth|GPS
```

I have tried using a multi-valued facet in which i declared it like this..

```
<dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general"
indexed="true"
stored="false"
multiValued="true"/>
```

And I have written code to split the value in the **Networking** attribute divided by **|**
like this..

```
value.split("\\|");
```

and finally using the `document.addField()` method, I have added the fields like this..

```
if(stValue.contains("|"))
{
System.out.println("stValue contains |");

String[] vals=stValue.split("\\|");

System.out.println("The length of vals is "+vals.length);

    for(String st:vals)
    {
        System.out.println("Adding field ("+solrPropertyName+" = "+st+")");
        document.addField(solrPropertyName, st);
    }
}
```

But still, I am displayed in the search like this..

**Networking**

Wifi|Bluetooth|GPS (2)

How could this be fixed? Thanks in advance. Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For each product index a field called `network`. Then for each query, use the method `addFacetField("network")`. This will return a list of the values in the field and their counts respective to the set of products that match your query. If you want to get all the possible facet values do a query for `*:*`.